# Select and show with specific data value JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a page with some divs which all have data-rank value.

```
<div class="game-play-rank" data-rank"1"></div>
<div class="game-play-rank" data-rank"2"></div>
<div class="game-play-rank" data-rank"3"></div>
etc...
```

in my js I have a variable which represents a persons score. I only want to show the data-rank value which is closest to (but higher than) the persons score.

e.g.

```
<div class="game-play-rank" data-rank"4"></div>
<div class="game-play-rank" data-rank"7"></div>
<div class="game-play-rank" data-rank"10"></div>

<script>
var score = 4;
</script>
```

I was going to do something like

```
$current = null;
$(".game-play-rank").each(function() {
    if(this.data("rank") > score && this.data("rank") < current.data("rank"))
        $current = this;
});
```

but I think doing the each loop is making "this" the HTML and I can't do the JQuery .data() function on it. How should I approach this?

Comment: Elements are not having class as `game-play-rank`. Use `$('[data-rank!=""]')`. `current` should be jQuery wrapped element and it should have `data-rank` attribute...

Comment: sorry I just forgot to add that in for my example. I cut out most of the stuff that's in my actual code so as not to make it too verbose.

Comment: Is it working ? If NO, be specific about what issue you are facing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to call this with jQuery selector, if not it's not a jQuery object that's why data attribute cannot be called

try this :

```
var current = null;
$(".game-play-rank").each(function() {
if($(this).data("rank") > score && $(this).data("rank") < current.data("rank"))
    current = $(this).data('rank');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$(this).data("rank")` instead of `this.data("rank")`

Answer (score 0):

To make it `jquery` object use `$(this)` instead of `this`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a jQuery object from a dom node the same way you would do with a DOM selector:

```
$('div').each(function(){
    var jQueryObject = $(this);
})
```

If you only want to support newer browsers, you can also use the DOM node's dataset property:

```
var rank = this.dataset.rank;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Comment: Thank you. much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

The $.each takes as a parameter a function, which can have 2 parameters, the index and the value of the each.

I mean :

```
$current = null;
$(".game-play-rank").each(function(i, val) {
    if($(val).data("rank") > score && $(val).data("rank") < current.data("rank"))
        $current = this;
});
```

can work as you want better than using a "this"